# why is my nslookup not always returning an IP?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, cmd, nslookup

I wrote an nslookup code but in some cases, it does not print the IP, it prints some domain.

I wrote a DNS packet that the dst IP is 8.8.8.8.
for example the domain "stackoverflow.com" will work but for this one "s.ytimg.com" it wont work and the answer will be "b'ytstatic.l.google.com.'"

```
# Creates DNS request
fullmsg = IP(dst = DST_IP)/UDP()/DNS(rd = 1,qd = DNSQR(qname = "s.ytimg.com"))
ans = sr1(fullmsg, verbose = 0)
print(ans[DNS].summary())# output: DNS Ans "b'ytstatic.l.google.com.'" expected: "172.217.17.78"
```

I expected that it will print the IP but like I said it does not print IP for every entered domain.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `CNAME` as the answer. You need to further resolve it. I.e.: check if the answer is a valid IP address. If it isn't try to resolve the answer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record